# Python Tuple Slicing

Tags: python, tuples, slice

Given that -1 goes back to the first term in a tuple, and the end index of a slice stops before that index, why does

```
x=(1,2,3,4,5)
x[0:-1]
```

yield

```
(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

instead of stopping at the index before the first which is 5?

Thanks

Comment: [This question has been answered before and very thoroughly.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/pythons-slice-notation)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

-1 does not go back to the first term in a tuple

```
x=(1,2,3,4,5)
x[-1]
```

yields

```
5
```

Answer (score 10):

It helps to think of the slicing points as *between* the elements

```
x = (   1,   2,   3,   4,   5   )
      |    |    |    |    |    |
      0    1    2    3    4    5
     -5   -4   -3   -2   -1
```

Comment: You could also say that the end index is non-inclusive.

Answer (score 5):

Slicing works like this:

```
x[start : end : step]
```

In your example, `start = 0`, so it will start from the beginning, `end = -1` it means that the end will be the last element of the tuple (not the first). You are not specifying `step` so it will its default value `1`.

This [link from Python docs](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#lists) may be helpful, there are some examples of slicing.

Comment: the `end` in `x[start : end : step]` would not be in the slice result.

Answer (score 0):

A -ve value in any python sequences means :

```
Val = len(sequence)+(-ve value)
```

Either start/stop from/to `len(sequence)+(-ve value)`, depending on what we specify.